# Celebrity says her favorite colour is "blueistic blue." What shade of blue does she refer to: light blue or dark blue or bright blue?

Tags: word-meaning

This is from a show with Nicole Kidman [73 questions](https://youtu.be/kI2ucw7hP34?t=129). (see 2:10-2:15)

The guy from the magazine asks her about her favorite colour and she says:

**"blueistic blue."** (I checked the subtitles.)

What kind of blue is that? And is this suffix used with other colours as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YouTube automatic subtitles are good but they are not infallible. Trust your ear more.

Nicole Kidman actually says "**bluest of blue**", which means *very* blue. "Bluest" is the superlative form of blue.